# Installing puppeteer throws error with "Failed to install script 'node install.js'"

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I am trying to install puppeteer, but it gives me following error message:

```
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@4.0.1 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
```

Both node and npm are up to date. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share in your question the following info so we can help you: (1) your exact Node version, (2) your environment/platform, (3) the method you are using for install (e.g.: `yarn add puppeteer`, `npm i puppeteer` etc., (4) the details of the project you are trying to install puppeteer (is it an existing Node project with a `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock`/`package-lock.json` or a brand new one in an empty folder).

Comment: My operating system is Linux Mint and I am using Visual Studio Code, node version is v8.10.0,  I am trying installing it via npm i puppeteer and in a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Node version is v8.10.0 which is not compatible with puppeteer 4.0.1 that you are trying to install.

Since [puppeteer 3.0.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/v3.0.0) Node.js v8.x.x is no longer supported.

**You have two options:**

1. Upgrading to Node v10.18.1+ on your Linux system (from Node.js [downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), latest LTS version: 12.18.1, or if you need multiple Node versions at the same time you can use [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (NVM)).
2. Installing the last version of puppeteer which was supported on Node v8.10.0. It was [puppeteer 2.1.1](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/v2.1.1) and can be installed with:

```sh
npm install puppeteer@2.1.1
```

or if you wouldn't be sure which one was the latest 2.x.x version: you can use `^`:

```sh
npm install puppeteer@^2.0.0
```

Of course like this you'd loose some functionality and need to make sure using this docs version: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

we can do

```sh
npm install --unsafe-perm=true
```

if package.json already contains the puppteer config's.